# Copy location constraint works wierd

Tags: rigging, armature, constraints

I have a foot and IK constraints on toes, so that when I move the leg, fingers deform, because their IK bones stayed where they were. I made a copy location constraint for each of the IK bones to follow the IK bones for leg, but when I move the leg forward, fingers go down, when I move leg upwards, fingers go  back... How can I fix it?

Comment: Apply rotation maybe? (`Ctrl`+`A`)

Comment: as @NoviceInDisguise has noted it is a problem of orientation  ( local spaces are not in the same orientation ) use Pose space with Offset to avoid that

Comment: @aky Let us know if it helps please :D

Comment: Applying rotaiton isn't possible, because it is all one armature and I don't have idea, what pose space with offset is.